# How to add items to an array in this specific sequence?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to follow the certain pattern:

Examples below are just examples, but in practice the array could be any size for e.g 100 items long and any item can be removed for e.g the 55th out of 100.

Add first item:

`const items = [1]`

Add second item:

`const items = [1, 2]`

Remove second item (2 in this case):

`const items = [1]`

Add third item

`const items = [1, 3]`

So in other words, everytime I add an item it should tally up by 1.

But when I remove an item from the array, and then add a new item I need to remember what the previous number which was was added and add 1 to it.

Another example:

`const items = [3, 4]`

Add an item:

`const items = [3, 4, 5]`

Remove the first item (3 in this case):

`const items = [4, 5]`

Add a new item:

`const items = [4, 5, 6]`

Thanks :)

Comment: "I need to remember what the previous number which was removed was and add 1 to it." Your example shows it's adding the 1 + previously added number instead of the previously removed number (which would be 4), should it be that, or 6 as your example shows?

Comment: My bad that wasn't explained correctly, when you remove an item and then add a new item it should add the number which is 1 greater then the previous add.

So add should always just add 1 each time.

When you remove an item it should remove whatever that number was when you added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to keep track of the count using a variable, and then use that variable each time you append to your array (making sure to also increment it each time):

```js
let count = 1;
const items = [];

const appendAndIncrementCount = () => {
  items.push(count);
  count += 1;
};

const log = () => console.log(JSON.stringify(items));

// "add first item"
appendAndIncrementCount();
log(); // [1]

// "add second item"
appendAndIncrementCount();
log(); // [1,2]

// "remove second item"
items.splice(1, 1);
log(); // [1]

// "add third item"
appendAndIncrementCount();
log(); // [1,3]

// ...etc.
```

Note that, instead of using a closure, you can also simply `array.push(count++);`, but I used the closure to illustrate that you can customize the functionality of your operation.

Comment: Thanks, but In this example why do we pop the first item before adding the second item?

Also we can remove any item at any position in the array for e.g the 55th item in an 100 item array.

Comment: @JoeConsterdine That's correct. Those mutations are just arbitrary examples, like the ones you gave in your question. If the mutations in your question weren't arbitrary, can you clarify the rules of their pattern?

Comment: I probably should have explained the example is just that, the array could be any size.

The rules are:

Imagine you have a shopping cart of 100 items.

You start with an empty array: []

When adding an item to the cart it will add 1:

const items = [1]

When removing an item from the cart it will remove that specific number for e.g:

const items = [1, 4, 5, 8, 9];

If you remove item '5' you will be left with:

const items = [1,4,8,9]

if you then add a new item to the cart:

const items = [1,4,8,9,10]

Comment: Joe, what is the problem? You don't know how to remove an arbitrary element from an array? Have you actually tried this answer with any other removal?

Comment: @JoeConsterdine Yes, that's exactly how the code in my answer works. I'll update it with the exact steps from your first example to give you more confidence.